# Term specific featured post on taxonomy archive pages

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to find a way to display a per term featured post on taxonomy archive pages.

So say you navigate to `url.com/my_taxonomy/my_term` it should show the featured post of `my_term` above the results of this page.

Making a post "`featured`" would be done by a custom field named "`featured`", which is a true/false field.

**Edit: the way to go...**

```
    <?php

    $obj = get_queried_object();
    $post_object = get_field('featured', $obj );

    if( $post_object ): 
// override $post
    $post = $post_object;
    setup_postdata( $post ); 

    ?>
<div class="featured">

</div>



<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go would be to create an archive template for your **taxonomy**.
Then you can catch the term requested with a function like `get_queried_object()`.
So now you can do a custom `WP_Query` querying for both your term and your meta 'featured'

Hope that makes sense

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: Yep, that absolutely makes sense. I went that route on my own as well. Added the code I used to my first post. Thanks for replying to me, wish I could upvote you.